# How to allow duplicate values in Map java?

Tags: java, android, collections

I am using Autocompletetextview so I want duplicates names to display... the name is coming from server...i tried some sample of java code below it's not working...

```
public class EmptyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap_searchresult = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_empty);
        hashMap_searchresult.clear();

        hashMap_searchresult.put("a1",new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d")));
        hashMap_searchresult.put("a1",new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("e","f","g","h")));

        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : hashMap_searchresult.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            ArrayList<String> value2222 = entry.getValue();
            Log.e("checkstatus"," key    " + key + " value : " + value2222.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

> This is the **Output** getting
>
> key :  a1  value : [e, f, g, h]

---

> **But i want output below like this**
>
> ```
>  key :  a1  value : [a, b, c, d]
>  key :  a1  value : [e, f, g, h]
> ```

Can anyone tell what should I use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is getting ugly, but you could you a map of lists of lists:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, List<List<String>>> hashMap_searchresult = new LinkedHashMap<>();

List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d")));
list.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("e", "f", "g", "h")));
hashMap_searchresult.put("a1", list);

for (Map.Entry<String, List<List<String>>> entry : hashMap_searchresult.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    List<List<String>> value2222 = entry.getValue();
    for (List<String> lst : value2222) {
        String[] arr = new String[list.size()];
        arr = lst.toArray(arr);
        System.out.println("checkstatus" + " key    " + key + " value : " + Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try the below type of collection:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> hashMap_searchresult = new LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();
```

which means you can create list of list of strings as value and thus can put multiple list over there. But you need to be careful while handling such data (especially while initializing the lists).

```
Set<String> keySet = hashMap_searchresult.keySet();
Iterator<String> iterator = keySet.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())    {
    String key = iterator.next();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> outerList = hashMap_searchresult.get(key);
    for(int index=0;index<outerList.size();index++)    {
        ArrayList<String> innerList = outerList.get(index);
        Log.e("checkstatus"," key    " + key + " value : " + innerList.toString());
    }  

}
```

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen he given me very clear code...so i gave you upvote..thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To have multiple lists as values for the same key, you need to put them in some kind of container like another list. This means you'd have a map type like the following:

```
Map<String, List<List<String>>>
```

now you can add and remove lists for specific keys. But keep in mind that you have to create a list for each key first before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try google MultiMap to make code simple.
Ref: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html